# Hollerith conversion

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile some very old Fortran (Fortran66) code and encountering some problem that I hope someone can comment or help me out to tackle the error. Specially, this old code uses tons of Hollerith constants (yeah...it is really old code) for text/characters. Needless to say, I get some warning messages and the code does not compile. Editing to try and change it to more modern text declarations would be virtually impossible because I am just not sure what code would break.

I am not expert in this case, so not sure what to do to fix this problem. I would appreciate some advice.

Here is the sample declaration statement

```
  IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)
  PARAMETER (MRTOT =10000000, MITOT =1000000, MNUMNP=18500)
  REAL*8 IHED( 9),CPSTM,CPETM,STTIM,EDTIM,ACCTIM,USETIM
  CHARACTER MNBLR*1, DUMMY*80
  CHARACTER*9 FILE1,FILE2
  CHARACTER*80 TITLE,FMT
  DIMENSION    RA(6000),T(12), NDOTLT(1000)
  DIMENSION IPR1(2,10),IPR2(2,10),UATMX(MNUMNP,2),VATMX(MNUMNP,2)
  EQUIVALENCE (IA,RA)
  DATA IPR2/20*0/,IPR1/20*0/
  DATA IIIEND/3HEND /,IIIEXE/3HEXE/,IIIEIG/3HEIG /
  COMMON /R/A ( MRTOT )
  COMMON /I/IA( MITOT )
  COMMON /JOINO/LPEL
  COMMON /HENNI/DACCUM( MNUMNP, 2 )
  character*5 input
```

and some error messages:

```
    DATA IIIEND/3HEND /,IIIEXE/3HEXE/,IIIEIG/3HEIG /
1
Warning: Legacy Extension: Hollerith constant at (1)
dynamic.f:618:72: Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)
dynamic.f:23:49:
DATA IIIEND/3HEND /,IIIEXE/3HEXE/,IIIEIG/3HEIG /
1
Warning: Extension: Conversion from HOLLERITH to INTEGER(4) at (1)
```

Comment: Have you tried to search for Hollerith on this site?

Comment: How do you compile the code? Which compiler (version)? Which compiler flags? Have you tried to enable any legacy flags?

Comment: The syntax error refers to an argument list, and is for line 23.  That error doesn't necessarily have anything to do with hollerith.  Are you showing us that line?  If so, which line is it?

Comment: I think the error referes to line 618 and it is some subroutine code which is not shown.

Comment: No IanH is probably right and it is line 23, but it is quite confusing. I'd rather see both lines.

Comment: I am using GNU FORTRAN compiler version 5.4.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and here is my linker and flags {FFLAG =  -O2 #-g -Wall

LDFLAGS = -lm

LINKER   = gfortran #ifc

FC            = gfortran #ifc} and this is line 23 :  DATA IIIEND/3HEND /,IIIEXE/3HEXE/,IIIEIG/3HEIG /

Comment: Please show line 618 too as I have requested. Not just the line but all relevant code around.

Comment: This is line 23: DATA IIIEND/3HEND /,IIIEXE/3HEXE/,IIIEIG/3HEIG /               line 618: CALL gidfile(x,y,ielnod,id,numnp,numel,neq,iout,delta)

Comment: Actually i m novice here how do i show u my full warinings/error and my subroutine code??

Comment: Please show the whole part of code which contains this line. We need to know where do all the `x,y,ielnod,id,numnp,numel,neq,iout,delta` come from and how does subroutine `gidfile` look like and where does it come from. Please see [mcve].

Comment: Thank you @VladimirF for your valuable time, i think i need to go thoroughly once again and then i will post my warnings/errors log with all the relevant code.